# How to find the list of all the class name in a file in python?

Tags: python, file, class

I am currently writing a python script to display all name of all the python files in a package and also all the name of the class a file contains.

scenario

```
#A.py

class apple:
      .
      .
class banana:
      .
      .

# Extracting_FilesName_className.py

 f=open("c:/package/A.py','r')     
 className=[]
 "Here i need to use some command to get all the class name within the file A.py and append it to className'  

  print file_name,className
```

out put A.py,apple,banana

I can use an old convention way where i could check for each line whether "class" string to is present and retrieve the className. But i want to know is there is a better way to retrieve all the class Name ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative that will also find nested classes and doesn't require importing of the file:

```
source = """
class test:
    class inner_class:
        pass
    pass

class test2:
    pass
"""

import ast
p = ast.parse(source)
classes = [node.name for node in ast.walk(p) if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)]
# ['test', 'test2', 'inner_class']
```

Answer (score 16):

Something like this:

```
>>> from types import ClassType
>>> import A
>>> classes = [x for x in dir(A) if isinstance(getattr(A, x), ClassType)]
```

Another alternative as @user2033511 suggested:

```
>>> from inspect import isclass
>>> classes = [x for x in dir(A) if isclass(getattr(A, x))]
```

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma oops! typo.

Comment: And I would use the classname `A` instead of `so` :)

Comment: Instead of `types` and `isinstance` one can use `inspect.isclass` instead, which will probably boil down to the same, but is easier to read, imho.

Comment: is that possible to get classes by defination order? default is sorted by name.

Comment: @metmirr You can get the line number using [`inspect.getsourcelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) and sort the list based on it.